# Generating set of a restricted space is the restriction of the generating set in the bigger space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ is the sample space and $X' ⊆ X$. I want to show that if $\mathcal{C}$ generates the $σ$-algebra $\mathcal{F} $ in $X$ and $\mathcal{C}' = $ {$A ∩ X' : A ∈ C$}, then $\mathcal{C'}$ generates the $σ$-algebra $\mathcal{F}'$ in $X’$. Is this true at all? If yes, how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(S,\mathcal B)$ and $(S',\mathcal B')$ are measurable space and $f\colon S\to S'$, then for a class $\mathcal C\subset \mathcal B'$, we have $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))$.

Use this with $S=X'$, $S'=X$ and $f(x)=x$ and notice that $i^{-1}(A)=A\cap X'$.